# How can I POST an image to DB via react native with the fetch API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, fetch

So I am trying to POST an image to a server via React Native and the fetch API.

```js
      fetch(`${API}/uploadAvatar`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: bearer,
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ file: result.uri }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          console.log({ json });
          // this console.log outputs:
          // "The format of the file should be jpg, png, jpeg.",
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log({ err });
        });
    }
```

`result` returns this:

```json
{
  "cancelled": false,
  "height": 1776,
  "type": "image",
  "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/18F84F29-CB72-4615-A68F-A00422D9B119/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540heythere%252Fkeep-up/ImagePicker/959E8BDE-FCF4-40C6-AF18-8F9EA852760D.jpg",
  "width": 1776,
}
```

Those are the calls on POSTMAN where you can see they work.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What would really help is if you go to Postman and click on "Code" which is next to the "Cookies" and beneath the "Save" button. Select JavaScript Fetch and see if the snippet has something that your code doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your postman shows that you're using form-data to upload the image, but in your code you're simply making a JSON post call without sending any form-data. You need to create a new `FormData` instance, and append data to it. In your case, you want to send the `result.uri` with the key `file`, this can be done using `formData.append('file', result.uri)`. Then you gotta send the formData instance as your body (with method as POST, in your case)

```
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', result.uri);

   fetch("api/SampleData", {
       body: formData,
       method: "post"
     }).then((response) => response.json())
     .then((json) => {
       console.log({
         json
       });
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log({
         err
       });
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can post images to the server with the help of Form Data by creating a JSON object of the file path, file name, and file type and append the object into the Form Data instance with the parameter. The path of the file is Platform-specific therefore you have to add conditions for the path. Please refer to the code snippet.

```
let Data = new FormData();
Data.append('file',
{ 
uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? result.uri: result.uri.replace('file://',''),
type: result.type,
name: result.uri.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
});
fetch("api/SampleData", {
   body: Data,
   method: "post",
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
 }).then((response) => response.json())
 .then((json) => {
   console.log({
     json
   });
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log({
     err
   });
 });
```